# Attempted to access an element as a type incompatible with the array

Tags: c#, smo

The following code gives me error:

> Attempted to access an element as a type incompatible with the array.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;

var server = new Server(@".\sqlexpress");
var database = server.Databases["mydemotest"];

var scripter = new Scripter(server);
scripter.Options.IncludeIfNotExists = true;
scripter.Options.ScriptSchema = true;
scripter.Options.ScriptData = true;

string scrs = "";
string tbScr = "";
foreach (Table myTable in database.Tables)
{
    if (myTable.IsSystemObject == true) continue;

    IEnumerable<string> tableScripts = scripter.EnumScript(new Urn[] { myTable.Urn });

    foreach (string script in tableScripts)
        scrs += script + "\n\n";
}

return (scrs + "\n\n" + tbScr);
```

I get an exception at this line  `IEnumerable<string> tableScripts = scripter.EnumScript(new Urn[] { myTable.Urn })`. How can I resolve the `ArrayTypeMismatchException`?

Comment: because of `scripter.Options.ScriptData = true;` this is not working i already tried  `myTable.Script(scriptOptions);`

Comment: Are we supposed to know what classes you're using? You'll need to provide more information on what these classes are coming from.  I _guess_ you're using the classes found in the [Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.aspx) namespace?

Comment: @JeffMercado question updated!